# Jest: Fail upon parsing a file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I'm using react with typecript and after adding swiper dependecy my tests start to fail.
[image]

These are my configuration:

jest.config.ts:

```
import type { Config } from '@jest/types';

const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
  verbose: true,
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!swiper|ssr-window|dom7/)'],
};
export default config;
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-flow'],
  plugins: [
    'babel-plugin-styled-components',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
      '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
    '\\.(css|less)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js',
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest',
  },
};
```

package.json

```
...
 "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "swiper/react": "swiper/react/swiper-react.js",
      "swiper/css": "swiper/swiper.min.css"
    },
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.css$": "jest-transform-css"
    }
  },
  "transformIgnorePatterns": "node_modules/(?!(swiper|ssr-window|dom7)/)",
...
```

Comment: Do you want to use ts-jest or babel? Do you want the jest config in package.json or jest.config.js? Is your project using es modules or commonjs?

Comment: @morganney Hey! I want to use babel, i want the jest config in the jest.config.js (or .ts if it works but I tried it before and it didnt work for me) and my project is using es modules.

Comment: @morganney can you help if you know how to set this up? I have been stuck on this problem for the last 2 weeks and its been a big hurdle for me to complete the project.